# Programmatically add reminder to iPhone calendar?

Tags: iphone

Can anyone have any idea about programmatically add reminder to iPhone calendar.

I searched the iPhone SDK documentation but didn't find anything.

Thanks and Regards
Jayaraj

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is available in iOS 4.x with EventKit.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to read [this EventKit sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes you can...

```
    #import <EventKit/EventKit.h>

...

    EKEventStore *eventDB = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *myEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];

    myEvent.title     = @"New Event";
    myEvent.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    myEvent.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    myEvent.allDay = NO;
    myEvent.notes = @"Test";

    [myEvent setCalendar:[eventDB defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    NSError *err;

    [eventDB saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]; 

    if (err == noErr) {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                initWithTitle:@"Event Created"
                message:@"Yay!?"
                delegate:nil
                cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];
       [alert release];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't. If you need this functionality you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug with Apple explaining why you need it.

Comment: This answer is outdated, consider removing.